# Why is numpy.take slow on the result of numpy.split when simple indexing is not?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, multidimensional-array

Consider the following code

```
import timeit
import numpy as np

MyArray = np.empty((10000, 10000, 1))
print((MyArray.size, MyArray.shape, MyArray.dtype, np.isfortran(MyArray)))
print(timeit.timeit(lambda: MyArray[0], number=10000))
print(timeit.timeit(lambda: MyArray.take(0), number=10000))

MyTwoArrays = np.empty((10000, 10000, 2))
MyArray = np.split(MyTwoArrays, 2, axis=2)[0]
print((MyArray.size, MyArray.shape, MyArray.dtype, np.isfortran(MyArray)))
print(timeit.timeit(lambda: MyArray[0], number=10000))
print(timeit.timeit(lambda: MyArray.take(0), number=1))
```

and its output on my system:

```
(100000000, (10000, 10000, 1), dtype('float64'), False)
0.05690493136299911
0.06236779451013045
(100000000, (10000, 10000, 1), dtype('float64'), False)
0.0569617025453055
1.6303121549025763
```

The two versions of `MyArray` are the same size, shape, data type and data ordering. Still, obtaining the 0th element is 300,000 times slower when using `numpy.take` with the result of `numpy.split`, compared to simple indexing with that same result or `numpy.take` with a "native" numpy array.

Why is that? Can I fix that?

*Update:*

This seems to be related to views: `MyArray = MyArray.copy()` fixes the problem. Still, I am interested in why `[0]` works equally as fast, while `numpy.take` slows down for views.

*Another update:*

I have noticed that the slow-down depends on the array dimension (not the number of array dimensions, but the number of array elements). I achieve access times of up to 8 seconds for a single 0th element. I find this is the most surprising aspect of this issue. Whatever numpy.take does internally, I see  no reason why this additional "level of indirection" should be slower to compute when indices are larger.

*Third update:*

Following @hpaulj's comment that `MyArray.take(0)` and `MyArray[0]` are not equivalent, here is a corrected code example. (I had made that mistake by means of my MATLAB intuition and stopped verifying my minimal example at one point. I do not want to replace the original example since hpaulj's answer might depend on it.)

```
import timeit
import numpy as np

for UseSplit in (True, False):
    if UseSplit:
        print("Using split")
        MyDoubleArray = np.random.rand(5000, 5000, 2)
        MyArray = np.split(MyDoubleArray, 2, axis=2)[0]
    else:
        print("Not using split")
        MyArray = np.random.rand(5000, 5000, 1)

    print((MyArray.size, MyArray.shape, MyArray.dtype, np.isfortran(MyArray)))


    NumpyTaking = MyArray.take(0)
    DirectIndexing = MyArray.item(0)
    assert (NumpyTaking == DirectIndexing)

    print("Take 1")
    print(timeit.timeit(lambda: MyArray.take(0), number=1))
    print("Index 1")
    print(timeit.timeit(lambda: MyArray.item(0), number=1))


    NumpyTaking = MyArray.take(0, axis=2)
    DirectIndexing = MyArray[:, :, 0]
    assert (NumpyTaking == DirectIndexing).all()

    print("Take many")
    print(timeit.timeit(lambda: MyArray.take(0, axis=2), number=1))
    print("Index many")
    print(timeit.timeit(lambda: MyArray[:, :, 0], number=1))
```

With this output on my (other) system:

```
Using split
(25000000, (5000, 5000, 1), dtype('float64'), False)
Take 1
0.2260607502818708
Index 1
2.1667747519799052e-05
Take many
0.44334302173084994
Index many
0.0005971935325195243
Not using split
(25000000, (5000, 5000, 1), dtype('float64'), False)
Take 1
2.851019410510247e-05
Index 1
2.0527339755549434e-05
Take many
0.13906132276656846
Index many
1.444516501325488e-05
```

Comment: `MyArray[0]` is really `MyArray[0,:,:]`, a view, a slice on the first dimension.  `MyArray[0]`, with `axis=None` ravels the array and returns the 1st element (this ravel is just a reshape).  `np.split` returns views (slices).  A ravel on such a slice will require a copy.

Comment: @hpaulj thanks, I have added an example that compares run times of two equivalent commands, with essentially the same conclusions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is a bit long and convoluted, but I think the key point is, `MyArray[0]` is a view in both constructs.  `MyArray.take` makes a copy in the 2nd case (`split`) case.  That `copy` takes much longer.

---

The 2 actions are not equivalent:

```
In [302]: MyArray = np.ones((10000, 10000, 1))
In [303]: MyArray[0].shape
Out[303]: (10000, 1)
In [304]: MyArray.take(0).shape
Out[304]: ()
```

`take` with `axis=None` (default), ravels the array.  Specifying the axis returns the same thing as `MyArray[0,:,:]`:

```
In [305]: MyArray.take(0,axis=0).shape
Out[305]: (10000, 1)
```

Using `ipython` `timeit` (and numpy 1.14)

```
In [306]: timeit MyArray[0].shape
425 ns ± 7.03 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
In [307]: timeit MyArray.take(0).shape
1.25 µs ± 11.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
In [308]: timeit MyArray.take(0,axis=0).shape
10.6 µs ± 22.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

I'm a little surprised that `take` is so much slower, though I've never had the impression that was meant to be a speed tool.  Rather it's a convenience for cases like:

```
In [311]: MyArray.take(0, axis=1).shape
Out[311]: (10000, 1)
In [313]: MyArray[:,0,:].shape
Out[313]: (10000, 1)
```

where specifying an axis by number rather than colons was easier to use in code.

> however, it can be easier to use if you need elements along a given axis.

When I construct `MyArray` via the split, the `take` timings get much worse

```
In [321]: timeit MyArray[0].shape
422 ns ± 5.54 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
In [322]: timeit MyArray.take(0).shape
713 ms ± 10.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
In [323]: timeit MyArray.take(0,axis=0).shape
705 ms ± 3.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

`ravel` is most of this extra time.  I think `take` has to make a copy:

```
In [324]: timeit MyArray.ravel()
710 ms ± 19.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

The construction step: `np.ones((10000, 10000, 2))` takes much longer, and I was afraid I'd get a memory error.  I'm using `ones` instead of `empty` to make sure the array is fully allocated before use.

This suggests that memory management issues are complicating the timings.

---

The databuffer pointer tells me whether an array is a view or not:

```
In [334]: MyArray.__array_interface__['data']
Out[334]: (139737581203472, False)
In [335]: MyArray2.__array_interface__['data']
Out[335]: (139737581203472, False)
```

`MyArray2` is like your `MyTwoArrays`.  So the split returns views, not copies.

But a `ravel` has to make a copy in the split case:

```
In [336]: MyArray.ravel().__array_interface__['data']
Out[336]: (139739981209616, False)
In [337]: MyArray2.ravel().__array_interface__['data']
Out[337]: (139737581203472, False)
```

Look at the databuffer for the indexing versus `take`:

```
In [343]: MyArray[0].__array_interface__['data']
Out[343]: (139737581203472, False)
In [344]: MyArray.take(0, axis=0).__array_interface__['data']
Out[344]: (34066048, False)
In [345]: MyArray.take(0).__array_interface__['data']
Out[345]: (33320032, False)
```

`MyArray[0]` is still a view, and thus relatively fast.

`take` on `MyArray` is a copy, both with the `axis` and without.

```
In [346]: timeit MyArray.copy()
701 ms ± 1.87 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

I should probably go back and check for copying in the first case, but the memory load of this session is dragging down the rest of my computing.

Comment: Thank you, this is very convincing, especially the part showing that 1) `take` and `ravel` use equal amounts of time and 2) `ravel` creates a copy.

Comment: I take away two things: 1) it is not the computation of view indices which take a lot of time as hypothesized by @sciroccorics; 2) my workaround (`MyArray = MyArray.copy()`) is effective for the exact reason that the copy operation is shifted away from the (repeated, in my case) `take`ing which has to copy for some reason otherwise. Both things are supported by my observation that the time to `take` depends on the size of the array.

Answer (score 1):

If you split the matrix without copying the data (i.e. view) you create one level of indirection that needs to be resolve for each loop step. This is clearly slow and explains the huge increase of computation time.

The only case when it does not happen is when the second half of the split is void, because numpy views always remove indirection for singleton lists. This can be observed if you edit your code with the following line:

```
... 
MyTwoArrays = np.empty((6000, 6000, 1))
MyArray = np.split(MyTwoArrays, [1], axis=2)[0]
...
```

The timings is now much faster with the second array (while there is still the same amount of data as previously).

On the other hand, if you copy half of the data in a new array, you "flatten up" this indirection, so the timings are again equivalent to the none-splitted array. It's the usual time vs. memory tradeoff

Finally: why is this effect only visible with `take` and not with fancy indexing? I can only guess (should be confirmed by analyzing source) that fancy indexing is smarter about the way it detects view indirection and is able to reorganize link structure before performing the actual loop. The two approaches clearly do not share the same code, because in my split-with-void example above, only the `take` function is speeded-up, not the fancy-indexing one...

Comment: Also, your example does not actually `split` anything as your rightly say, so I guess you are just skipping the actual problem. I *do* want to split my array in half.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include my previous comment, and answer your last question

Comment: Thanks. This still does not answer my question to the extent that I expected, but it's a start. Some more issues still, though: "The only case when it does not happen is when the second half of the split is void, because numpy views always remove indirection for singleton lists." Is there a reference for that? What does that mean in your example? You changed two things, the depth dimension of MyArray and the split parameter. With 1 element, well, you are not actually splitting anything (is that what you want to say)? Does the array split parameter have significance, compared to my scalar one?